# Как правильно реализовать безопасную регистрацию пользователя в клиент-серверном WPF-приложении?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Для ввода пароля использую ‘PasswordBox’ по понятным причинам. Но мне нужно как-то вычислить его хеш для регистрации на сервере. Получается, придется доставать все символы последовательно с ‘SecureString’ и вся суть использования зашифрованных строк здесь пропадает. Как правильно организовать безопасное получение пароля пользователя и регистрацию его на сервере?

Comment: 1. HTTPS
2. асимметричная подпись открытой части ключа сертификата сервера, на стороне сервера расшифровать приватным ключом.

Comment: Это относится к безопасной передачи данных, но меня интересует хранение, а не отправка на сервер. Ведь SecureString создан для безопасного хранения информации. По этому я и спрашиваю как правильно им пользоваться, а не какой протокол передачи данных выбрать.

Comment: Зачем вам хранить пароль на стороне клиента?

Comment: Чтобы вычислить его хеш